# Spring Boot + OAuth2 + Google Login - How to implement logout

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-session

I have a Auth Server implementation with Spring Boot + OAuth2 + Login through Google. And a resource server for my backend data services. I have used JDBC token store. Everything works great. But I am having difficulty in understanding logout implementation. Currently, whenever user clicks on logout I just delete the token from the browser local storage but the session stays active in the Auth server hence I don't need to login again. What I want is whenever use clicks on logout I want to invalidate the session and force him to login again.

Is there any nice way to do this? I currently don't have any logout configuration in my Spring Boot Auth server configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try registering a LogoutSuccessHandler to do that. Something along the lines of:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
public class SecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        return new DefaultTokenServices();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("myResourceId");
        resources.tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       // configure http security here...

        http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler() {
                      @Override
                      public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                  HttpServletResponse response,
                                                  Authentication authentication) {
                          OAuth2AccessToken token = tokenServices().getAccessToken((OAuth2Authentication) authentication);
                          tokenServices().revokeToken(token.getValue());
                      }
                  });

    }
}
```